Emails not recevied when using redis + celery + django
I'm trying to send emails by celery instead of the normal way to sending emails.
I use redis as a message broker technique,
I have install redis on specific server and I add those settings to my django app
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://ip:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://ip:6379"

also I have create task for the celery to do,
from time import sleep

from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail


@shared_task()
def send_feedback_email_task(email_address, message):
    """Sends an email when the feedback form has been submitted."""
    sleep(20)  # Simulate expensive operation that freezes Django
    send_mail(
        "Your Feedback",
        f"\t{message}\n\nThank you!",
        "custom_email@somedomain.com",
        [email_address],
        fail_silently=False,
    )

in addition I have added all the email configuration,
the console doesn't show any error, it shows that the task if successfully done, but the email never sent to the email_address
INFO/MainProcess] Task feedback.tasks.send_feedback_email_task[9bda58a9-c269-4c04-b4f0-10e7c41bbe22] received
and when I do redis-cli monitor in server, the email appear in the console with the same body that I have wrote in the django app form
so why is the email not delivered ?
any help would be appreciated ..
